# Java detect if class is a proxy

Tags: java, testing, proxy, mocking, cglib

Is it possible to detect if a class is a **proxy** (**dynamic**, **cglib** or **otherwise**)?

Let classes `A`and `B` implement a common interface `I`. Then I need to define a routine `classEquals` of signature

```
public boolean classEquals(Class<? extends I> a, Class<? extends I> b);
```

such that it evaluates to *true* only if `a.equals(b)` or `Proxy(a).equals(b)`, where `Proxy(a)` denotes a dynamic proxy of type `A` (dynamic, cglib or otherwise).

---

With the assistance of `@Jigar Joshi`, this is what it looks like so far:

```
public boolean classEquals(Class a, Class b) {
    if (Proxy.isProxyClass(a)) {
        return classEquals(a.getSuperclass(), b);
    }
    return a.equals(b);
}
```

The **problem** is that it doesn't detect e.g., a **CGLIB** proxy.

Comment: In your `test` method, I suppose `Proxy(A.class)` returns a proxy object for A. What should be the result of `test(new A(), A.class)`?

Comment: @Arian, it should evaluate to true

Comment: So you don't want to detect proxies, but you want to find instances of a class, even if they are generated by an unknown mocking/proxy framework? What about `instanceof`?

Comment: @Arian, good comment. Although I'm working with `Classes` and not `Objects`, which unfortunately doesn't let me use `instanceof`

Comment: CGLIB provides a `Proxy.isProxyClass` in its own packages. That might detect them.

Comment: "true only if a.equals(b) *and* Proxy(a).equals(b)" did you mean 'or'?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`Proxy.isProxyClass(Foo.class)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#isProxyClass%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Awesome in that it detects a `DynamicProxy`, yet doesn't seem to recognize Mockito created CGLIB proxies .

Comment: do `Foo.getClass().getName()`

Comment: In case of CGLIB proxy use Enhancer.isEnhanced(class)

Answer (score 2):

no, in general you can't tell if an object is a proxy. and that's simply because it's hard to define what is a proxy. you can implement an interface and use it as a proxy, you can use cglib, asm, javassist, plastic, jdk or generate bytecode on the fly by yourself. it is no different than loading xxx.class file.

what you are thinking about is probably checking if the object is created by cglib, asm or other **specific** library. in such case - usually yes. most libraries have their own fingerprint that can be discovered. but in general it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

If `instanceof` is acceptable, then [`clazz.isInstance(b)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) should work as well.

**Edit:**
I wrote that before reading your modified answer. There is a similar method for classes as well:

[`b.isAssignableFrom(a)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't seem to apply nicely to [class-to-class](http://ideone.com/R9hLO) comparisons.